# Php storing multi language strings inside an object

Tags: php, string, object, multilingual

I'm using the following function to store user messages in two languages in javascript:

```
function user_messages(es_ES, en_EN) 
{
     this.es_ES = es_ES;
     this.en_EN = it_IT;
}
var um_duplicated_input = new user_message('Contenido duplicado','Duplicated content');
```

It may not be the best practice but is being really handy for me to get user messages in my code by language, using the locale value. I would like to know how to achieve something as simple to declare and handle in PHP instead building new arrays all the time. Been looking at stdclass but can't get it to work properly.

Comment: Could you elaborate what did you try, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: All the examples I've seen are way too complex for declaring each value. I haven't found a way to declare it in a single line like in javascript apart from new independent arrays instead reusable stuff.

Comment: You can convert your `js` to `php` by creating a class with your 2 properties. You can assign your values in the constructor or add a separate method.

Comment: Please update the answer with examples you've seen and explanation why they do not solve your problem. Did you try php objects http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the help of people like Alex Blex who rather prefer to question user's legitimacy instead helping them. Here is a working approach for those who may be looking in future for something similar (which I was thinking was the main purpose of this site) It could surely be better but I don't know how to make it simpler or smarter.

```
 class internal_message
 {
    public $message = array();

    public function setMsg($index, $newval)
    {
        $this->message[$index] = $newval;
    }

    public function getMsg($index)
    {
        return $this->message[$index];
    }
}
```

This way, you have to do a new declaration for every language, but in fact it is more safe and clear. I'm starting to feel really disappointed about this site, specially regarding topics like the english language quality of the posts: in my case, I'm Spanish, from Spain, and I dare you to speak as good Spanish as I do speak English. I also speak Deutch and Catalan. But this is not a place for languages, in fact, if somebody misspells something it will enrich your database with a content that somebody will also misspell when searching in Google.
I don't understand all this classism and attitude in recent times.

```
$error_message_wrong_pass = new internal_message;

$error_message_wrong_pass->setMsg("es_ES", "Password incorrecto");

$error_message_wrong_pass->setMsg("es_ES", "Wrong Password");

//To print them out

$error_message_wrong_pass->getMsg("es_ES");
```